# Extracting only numbers from data in mysql query

Tags: mysql

In mysql table, the data has special characters (.) and (_) mainly next to numbers. I'd like to extract only the numbers stripping the characters in mysql query. My current query is like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT Date, Tenext FROM tbdata";
```

In this query, I need this only for the second field name (Tenext).
How can I do this in the mysql query? any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? And are there only digits, dots and underscores in the strings or can there be any character in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TRIM function, for example:

```
mysql> SELECT TRIM(BOTH '_' FROM '_21_' );
21
```

So in your case, to remove all _ characters, you can use something like:

```
 $query = "SELECT Date, TRIM(BOTH '_' FROM Tenext) as Tenext FROM tbdata";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure it's just periods and underscores, this should do it:

```
SELECT 
Date,
TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Tenext, '.', ''), '_', '')) as Tenext
FROM tbdata
```